# html2canvas not displaying images in child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I am trying to work with html2canvas to create an image out of a div

Brief:

- I have an image (png) with a transparent area in it
- I have another image (can be jpg or png) that will be dragged/resized
  to look good inside the transparent area of the above image using a
  helper div
- I have the helper div that will have highest z-index with draggable
  and resizable

After user is happy he can click "done editing" to create a canvas with end result showing all images

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="artwork">
    <img src="http://preview.ibb.co/gsvuPR/photo1.png" alt="photo1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div id="img">
    <img src="http://puckerupbuttercup.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/0092-happy-alone.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div id = "dragger">
  </div>
</div>
  <a href="#d" id="done">
  done editing
  </a>


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
#container {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px
}
#artwork {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

#artwork img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px
}

#img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#img img {
  position: relative
}
#dragger {
  border: dashed 3px grey;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: all-scroll
}
#done {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 444;
  padding; 5px;
  background: yellow
}


$("#img img").css("max-width",$("#artwork img").width());
$("#img img").css("max-height",$("#artwork img").height());
$("#dragger").css("max-width",$("#artwork img").width()-5);
$("#dragger").css("max-height",$("#artwork img").height()-5);
var img_h = $("#img img").height()-5;
var img_w = $("#img img").width()-5;

var right = $("#artwork img").width()-img_w-5;
var bottom = $("#artwork img").height()-img_h-5;

$("#dragger").width(img_w);
$("#dragger").height(img_h);

$("#dragger").draggable({
  axis: 'xy', 
  containment : [0,0,right,bottom],
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#img img").css('top', ui.offset.top +'px');
    $("#img img").css('left', ui.offset.left +'px');
  }
});

$("#dragger").resizable({
    containment: "parent"
});

$( "#dragger" ).on( "resize", function( event, ui ) {
    $("#img img").css('width', ui.size.width +5+'px');
  $("#img img").css('height', ui.size.height +5+'px');
  var img_h = $("#img img").height()-5;
    var img_w = $("#img img").width()-5;
  var right = $("#artwork img").width()-img_w-5;
    var bottom = $("#artwork img").height()-img_h-5;
  $("#dragger").draggable({
  axis: 'xy', 
  containment : [0,0,right,bottom],
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#img img").css('top', ui.offset.top +'px');
    $("#img img").css('left', ui.offset.left +'px');
  }
});
});

$("#done").on("click",function(){
 $("#dragger").toggle();
 html2canvas($("#container"), {
   allowTaint: true,
   logging: true,
   onrendered: function (canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
   }
 });
});
```

All javascript is on ready
Everything work good in terms of resizing/dragging but html2canvas is not doing its job to display the images in a canvas for user to save

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p3vzgbzo/5/

I have tried this code locally with the images on same path to the page with no luck

I tried the DataToURL as well and didn't return any image

Ultimately I would like the rendered image to be uploaded to the server if possible as well
I am thinking the image needs to be converted to base code?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either the images in the `#container` must come from the same origin as the page, or you will have to embed them via base64.

[Working JSFiddle with base64 images](https://jsfiddle.net/09jkep0s/)

Comment: the page and the images are in the same directory (on my local server) it doesn't work. However your suggestion works which is converting the image to base64. Any suggestions as why wouldn't it work without doing so? I thought the "allowTaint" is to render images properly, no?

Comment: my bad actually. the local server was not running :)! all good now. Marking your reply as the answer because it actually works the solution you provided thank you

Answer (score 2):

This solution also will help someone. Elements with the absolute position are not rendering by default. Make sure all your elements are not absolute in position.