# How to capture a div as an image with onclick() and save locally?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am having difficulty to capture div which has multiple images as an image and save it in local folder with default name.Can anybody help me please?

```
Js Code

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn-one").click(function(){
//var testdiv = document.getElementById("testdiv");
    html2canvas($("#rocket-image"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(myImage);
        }
    });
});
});

HTML code
<div id="rocket-image" class="rocket-holder"> 
<img id="mainDeckel" src="images/image-1.png" alt="" > 
<img id="mainKorper" src="images/image.png" alt="" >
<img id="mainAccess" src="images/image.png" alt="" >
img id="mainDusen" src="images/image.png" alt="" > 
 </div>
<a id="btn-one" href="" class="btn-one">Capture</a id=""> </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48609907/8023799

Comment: Its not dubilcate but I took hint from thid code but its not working...

Comment: @yogZ can u please help me out..